# Is the $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty \zeta(k) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Let us vertically add $\zeta(k)$ for all integer values of $k$. We would get :

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \zeta(k) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty 1^k + \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty 2^k + \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty 3^k+\cdots$$

For ($r\neq1$), it is easy to see that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty r^k  = 0$.

We know that in these kind of situations, we would derive the same answer at $r=1$ by continuation of  the pattern, just like finding $1+2+4+8+\cdots$ is equal to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ at $x=2$ though the value logically only holds at $-1 < x < 1$.

We can even prove that the value is zero at $r=1$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^0} = \zeta(0) = \frac{-1}{2}$$

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} 1^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^0} = \zeta(0) = \frac{-1}{2}$$

$1^k$ at $(k=0) = 1$

Adding the above three would prove that $$\sum_{k=-∞}^∞ 1^k = 0$$.
Substituting all of this in the initial equation, we get:

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \zeta(k)= 0$$

Is the above correct? Does this give any information about the zeta function that we don't know?

Note: Though some of these series are divergent, they can still be assigned a value through analytic continuation. Take for example $1+2+4+8+...$, though it is divergent, it can be assigned a value of $-1$ through the 2-adic metric. An easy way to see is:

$S=1+2+4+8+...$

$S=1+2(1+2+4+8+...)$

$S=1+2S$

$S=-1$

Any help will be supported. Thank you.

Comment: *"For $r\neq1$, it is easy to see that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty r^k  = 0$"*. Really? Also, the expression above this doesn't make sense unless the sums converge, which they don't.

Comment: First of all, it is not necessary for a series to converge to have a value. An example would be 1+2+4+8+... = -1. Though it does not make logical sense, it does hold true. This is all part of analytic continuation.

Comment: And lastly, it is actually pretty obvious that $\sum_{k=-∞}^∞ r^k = 0$. We should add $\sum_{k=0}^∞ r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$ and $\sum_{k=-∞}^{-1} r^k = \frac{1}{r-1}$ . This shows that $\sum_{k=-∞}^∞ r^k = 0$

Comment: What does "full knowledge of the subject" mean? In stead of disqualifying effectively everyone from the discussion, include the necessary details to have any of the above make sense.

Comment: Sorry for not being polite. Do you find anything wrong with my explanation?

Comment: Please clarify what notion of convergence you are working with.

Comment: There is no convergence. Take the example. Though the sum of 1+2+4+8+... obviously does not converge, it does have an assigned value of -1.

Comment: Then please clarify how you assign values to these infinite sums.

Comment: Which infinite sum? 1+2+4+8+... ?

Comment: No, at least all of the infinite sums in your question.

Comment: Tell me one by one which sums you don't understand

Comment: I do not understand *any* of the sums, not in the least. I can vaguely make sense of *some* of them in *some* way, but I want to know what *you* mean by these sums. If you cannot make precise what you mean, then there is no point in continuing this conversation, as then you do not even remotely have the beginnings of a question.

Comment: I suggest the link below for you to understand more.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw

Comment: I happen to have seen the video before. I've also completed a couple of graduate courses in analytic and algebraic number theory and related subjects. Neither of these help answer my question to you. If you're not willing to put any effort into the question, don't expect others to.

Comment: Haran, you might be interested in this discussion of mine : http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/ProblemWithBellmatrix.pdf A couple of years I was thinking of a very similar problem finding that assuming it would easily be possible to use that scheme of changing order in a double series runs in very impressive "black holes"... Of course, some of them can be removed. But it needs careful analyses... And I guess your assumption does not work...

Comment: Is there any progress on this or, is there any way to correct this to get any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The Dirichlet series only works for $k = \Re k\ge 1$ (the famous $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots = -1/12$ is utter nonsense).

(2) $\zeta(1) = \infty$.

(3) Rearranging wildly a double sum can lead to more nonsense.